# Trying to get a nice format output, easy Python

Tags: python

```
board = []
for integer in range(1,6):
    board.append("O")
print(str(board)*5)
```

That's my code. My problem is that the output doesn't come out as a 5x5 grid. Am I missing another for loop? (I know I could probably use list comprehensions as well).

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `5x5` grid, you could `join` the results ...

```
'\n'.join([' '.join(board)]*5)
```

example:

```
>>> board = ['0']*5
>>> print '\n'.join([' '.join(board)]*5)
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

To get the output you're looking for, you can do

```
>>> board = [['0'] for _ in range(5)]
>>> board
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
>>> print '\n'.join(str(board) for _ in range(5))
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']]
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to get five rows of "[['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O']]"

Comment: thank you! Does the board variable's creation count as a list comprehension?

Comment: Yes.  `board` is created in a list comprehension.  Then I use a generator expression in `join`

Comment: Does the "_" in the for mean anything special or just your choice for the iterator?

Comment: @algebr '_' is just a convention to say I need a variable here, but I'm not going to use it for anything.

Comment: As a general rule, do not use join when printing into columns. Your columns will NOT align when you have multiple characters per data point. Learn this early and it will help you when you need to print your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [22]: board = [['O'] * 5 for _ in range(5)]

In [23]: print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in board))
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the newline:

```
 print(('0'*6+'\n')*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

**YOU SHOULD NOT USE *JOIN* TO PRINT DATA INTO COLUMNS BECAUSE THEY WILL NOT ALIGN WHEN YOU HAVE A VARIABLE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS IN YOUR DATA. USE STRING FORMATTING INSTEAD**.

```
boardLst = [[0 for i in range(1,6)]]*5
for board in boardLst:
    print "  %4d"*len(board) % tuple(board), "\n"

 0     0     0     0     0 

 0     0     0     0     0 

 0     0     0     0     0 

 0     0     0     0     0 

 0     0     0     0     0
```

The number four in the string formatter indicates the minimum amount of space between characters.

Now if you create a list which has a variable length of characters like below you can print nice columns:

```
import random
boardLst = [[random.randint(1,125) for i in range(1,5)] for _ in range(8)]
for board in boardLst:
    print " %5d "*len(board) % tuple(board), "\n"


  107     93     10     73  

   65     68     81     61  

   49     75     58     18  

   48     78     18     37  

   82      4     78    101  

   20      9     68     86  

   24     77     20     52  

   20    120     93     21
```